# Improving Xamarin forms rendering performance

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin.forms, rendering

I have a feature in my Xamarin application that involves generating sections for data entry based on the number of Observations which is an input from the user. If the user inputs 3, then 3 sections will be generated and if the user enters 100 then 100 sections are generated. I am facing an issue when I enter values more than 10 or 20 as the application begins to hang indefinitely. Since I cannot cap the input from the user I need to somehow fix this issue.

```
var newSections = new List<ISection>();
for (int i = currentLength; i < UserInput; i++)
{
    var newSection = DataEntryAttribute.SectionFactories();
    newSections.Add(newSection);
```

The above code snippet is the one which keeps generating the sections until it reaches the number entered by the user.

Any help or insights on possible ways to quicken up this process is appreciated.

Comment: only generate as many as will fit on the page.  Generate the rest on demand, or in a background task.

Comment: It hangs indefinitely? Are you saying it hangs forever?

Comment: I've had some good luck using CollectionView to display longer lists of complicated custom layouts containing mixed content with decent performance. It handles the loading/unloading stuff as it comes into view when you scroll automatically. However beware, it's an experimental feature still as far as i know. To use it, you have to use `Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");` in OnCreate() of your main activity.

Comment: When i say it hangs indefinitely i mean the app freezes for a good 30-40 seconds after a large number such as 60 or 100 is entered and throws the alert "Your app is  not responding" Then i click wait and again it takes about 10-20 seconds for it to behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

> when I enter values more than 10 or 20 as the application begins to
> hang indefinitely

Your app hangs indefinitely because the UI thread has been blocked and you have to wait those task finish then it will behave normally.

If you don't have to update the UI, you can perform those actions in a background thread so that it won't block the UI thread and your app won't hang:

```
public void test()
{

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var newSections = new List<ISection>();
        await for (int i = currentLength; i < UserInput; i++)
        {
            var newSection = DataEntryAttribute.SectionFactories();
            newSections.Add(newSection);
            ...
        }

        //update UI
    });
}
```

If you need to update UI at the same time, you should generate them on demand as mentioned in the comment. Also have a try with [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) and [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/).